# Why does my pong game freeze after the ball hits the bottom and it doesn't display the "Game Over" screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a high school student and also a python enthusiast. I am trying to make a pong game in python and most of it worked but I am trying to make the program wait 3 seconds before the ball starts moving and when the ball hits the bottom the program just freezes and it doesn't display the "Game Over" screen. Would anyone be able to help me with this? Here is the code I am working on.

```
 from tkinter import *
 import random
 import time

 class Ball:
     def __init__(self, canvas, color, size, paddle):
         self.canvas = canvas
         self.paddle = paddle
         self.id = canvas.create_oval(15, 15, size, size, fill=color)
         self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
         self.xspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)
         self.yspeed = -1
         self.hit_bottom = False
         self.score = 0

     def draw(self):
         self.canvas.move(self.id, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
         pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
         if pos[1] <= 0:
             self.yspeed = 9
         if pos[3] >= 400:
             self.hit_bottom = True
         if pos[0] <= 0:
             self.xspeed = 9
         if pos[2] >= 500:
             self.xspeed = -9
         if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
             self.yspeed = -9
             self.xspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)
             self.score += 1

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0, 168, 20, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.move_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.move_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.xspeed, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.xspeed = 0
        if pos[2] >= 500:
            self.xspeed = 0

    def move_left(self, evt):
        self.xspeed = -12
    def move_right(self, evt):
        self.xspeed = 12

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Pong")
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, bg='#ff4fea')
canvas.pack()
label = canvas.create_text(5, 5, anchor=NW, text="Score: 0")
tk.update()
paddle = Paddle(canvas, '#2be2ff')
ball = Ball(canvas, '#ddff00', 38, paddle)

while ball.hit_bottom == False:
    ball.draw()
    paddle.draw()
    canvas.itemconfig(label, text="Score: "+str(ball.score))
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

while ball.hit_bottom == True:
    print
    go_label = canvas.create_text(250,200,text="Game Over Play Again")
tk.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `time.sleep` in a tkinter application; use `root.after` instead.
You also do not need to create your own game loop inside a while loop; `tk.mainloop` does it for you.
calling `update` or `update_idle_tasks` is rarely necessary; let tkinter handle all these low levels actions for you.

Here is a working version of your Pong app that addresses the main issues, and answers your question. It does not restart the game, you will have to work this out by yourself. Maybe you will want to place the game logic in a class that will handle the restarting ans setting up for you? Please ask a new question if you are having difficulties.

I changed the star import to `import tkinter as tk` which keeps the namespace tidy, and I renamed your variable `tk`
using `root` instead.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class Ball:

    def __init__(self, canvas, color, size, paddle):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(15, 15, size, size, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        self.xspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)
        self.yspeed = -1
        self.hit_bottom = False
        self.score = 0

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.yspeed = 9
        if pos[3] >= 400:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.xspeed = 9
        if pos[2] >= 500:
            self.xspeed = -9
        if self.hit_paddle(pos):
            self.yspeed = -9
            self.xspeed = random.randrange(-3,3)
            self.score += 1

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2] and \
                pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
            return True
        return False


class Paddle:

    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 168, 20, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.move_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.move_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.xspeed, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.xspeed = 0
        if pos[2] >= 500:
            self.xspeed = 0

    def move_left(self, evt):
        self.xspeed = -12

    def move_right(self, evt):
        self.xspeed = 12


def run_game():
    ball.draw()
    paddle.draw()
    canvas.itemconfig(label, text="Score: "+str(ball.score))
    if not ball.hit_bottom:
        root.after(10, run_game)
    else:
        canvas.create_text(250, 200, text="Game Over Play Again")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Pong")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, bd=0, bg='#ff4fea')
    canvas.pack()
    label = canvas.create_text(5, 5, anchor=tk.NW, text="Score: 0")
    paddle = Paddle(canvas, '#2be2ff')
    ball = Ball(canvas, '#ddff00', 38, paddle)

    run_game()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it. I understand all the changes you made!!! This has been a great help.